# Date Format in Between Convertion

Tags: php

In my Database i have 10-12-2017 i tried to convert it using this function but it does not work for me

```
DATE_RECEIVE_MX BETWEEN 
 to_date('2017-10-01','MM-DD-YYYY')  AND to_date('2017-10-12,'MM-DD-YYYY');
```

Comment: is `to_date('2017-10-12,'MM-DD-YYYY');` typo error? there is one `'` missing

Comment: 1) This is not PHP code. 2) You haven't told us what database you're using (MySQL? PostgreSQL? MS SQL Server?). 3) '2017-10-01' is clearly not in 'MM-DD-YYYY' format. 4) You haven't told us what error you get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is mysql you need to use date_format('2017-10-01','%m-%d-%Y')

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/tr/class.datetime.php) class.

```
$dbFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $yourDataFromDB);
$yourFormat = $dbFormat->format('Y-m-d');
```

This will convert 10-12-2017 to 2017-12-10

Answer (score 0):

You should use a proper positio  and format   string for  Year,  month, day  .. `%Y-%m-%d`

```
 DATE_RECEIVE_MX BETWEEN 
   str_to_date('2017-10-01','%Y-%m-%d')  AND to_date('2017-10-12','%Y-%m-%dY'
```